# Unable to see Add-in on iPad from Add-in Catalog from Office 365 Admin Center

Tags: ipad, ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins

I have developed and deployed that Add-in to the Office 365 Admin Center under the Add-in Catalog.

I can access the Add-in in my Desktop Client for Word and in Online Word as well, but when I try to access the same Add-in from an iPad, I am unable to find an option for Organization Add-ins.

Can anybody help me on this?

**UPDATE:**

After seeing @Marc's reply. I have posted a request on UserVoice. For those, who think this feature should be a part of the Office 365, please vote here.
[UserVoice link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19003873-allow-add-ins-on-ipad-from-centralized-deployment)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, deploying to iPad using [Centralized Deployment](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) isn't supported. Looking at the documentation, it doesn't reference iPad at all which is an oversight. I've updated the documentation to clarify that iPad is not supported.

For deploying to an iPad, you can [side-load the add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac). Keep in mind that this would need to be done on each device so it isn't suitable for broad deployment. Depending on the add-in and it's audience, a better solution might be to publish via the [Office Store](https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/submit-add-ins-and-web-apps-to-the-office-store). This would allow iPad user's to easily attach your add-in to documents.

As to supporting iPad via Centralized Deployment in the future, I would recommend adding this suggestion to Office's [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). This is the best way to ensure this remains top of mind of the product teams.

Comment: Thanks @Marc for the detailed answer. We are in the process of development and we wanted a QA environment and for that purpose, we have deployed the add-in to Office 365/SharePoint Add-in Catalog. It looks like we will have to live with SideLoading for now... :(

Comment: For dev/test, side loading isn't too bad. Remember you only side load the manifest file. Once your manifest is working, you're just republishing the web site on the server.

Comment: Yes. But some of our corporate customers might want to deploy the add-in locally. Once that stage comes, we will face a limitation then, I guess....

Answer (score 1):

Naveed,

Unfortunately we don't currently support deployment of Add-Ins via Centralized Deployment on the iPad. We don't have any definite plans to support it as yet as I haven't received feedback from companies that they want the support but happy to consider it with enough positive feedback

Thanks
Phil